# Java if else on partial match

Tags: java, selenium

I've moved into Selenium WebDriver, and still finding the most confusing examples.

I need to be able to read a string (succeeded) run a conditional that asks If specific text is present.

For the sake of this text.

```
String oneoff = "Jeff is old"
```

I need to match on Jeff, see code below, as long as Jeff exists in the string, I want to return true. If Jeff doesn't exist, then I will check for oh say 50-75 other names.  However the string may contain their name and additional text that cannot be controlled.  so I have to do a partial match.

Question 1. am I screwed and will have to build each regex expression in that crazy format that I have been seeing, or am I missing something obvious?

Question 2. Will someone for my sanity please show me the proper way to match on Jeff, with the possibility of text being before and after the name Jeff.

Thank you!

```
String oneoff = driver.findElement(By.id("id_one_off_byline"))
        .getAttribute("value");
System.out.println("One Off is:" + oneoff);
if (oneoff.matches("Jeff")) {
    System.out.println("It is Jeff");
} else {
    System.out.println("it is not jeff");
}
```

This is just the functional part of the code,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> as Jeff exists in the string, I want to return true

Then you probably should test it with

```
if (oneoff.contains("Jeff"))
```

since `matches` use regex as parameter, so `if (oneoff.matches("Jeff"))` would return true only if `oneoff = "Jeff"`.

Comment: The way to use `matches()` in a contains context would be `if(oneoff.matches("(.*)Jeff(.*)"));` I believe? Though there should be no reason to do so.

Comment: Tested- and worked ... Thank you, I think what happened is I had tried contains earlier but had some other syntax incorrect so I thought it had failed on me. and moved onto matches. I know it was a simple answer, but for some of us, that can be the stumbling block! So truly appreciate it.

Comment: @Nashibukasan yes, to make `match` "find" some String inside other String it should be surrounded with `.*` but that would be overkill in this situation IMHO

Comment: @michaelReid Glad your sanity is safe now :)

Comment: Once I had a syntax error in my first string.contains() statement that I didn't catch.  I wandered down the rabbithole.  Which led me to string.matches() thankfully I asked here before I kept going :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use match() for the code you have supplied. Instead use oneoff.equals("String") for string matching. Match() is more for a regex expressions. You could also use oneoff.contains("String") if you want to return true even if the string only exists as a subset of the target string.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (oneoff.contains("Jeff")) {
    System.out.println("It is Jeff");
} else if (!oneoff.contains("Jeff")) {
    System.out.println("it is not jeff");
}
```

I think you should improve your code to be like this, because java probably didn't recognize else string if contained with other "jeff" maybe "JEef" or "JEEF" or even maybe "Jeef "

I hope it works, I used to found same bug like yours and I try this way to overcome it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight on the next piece shadrach I appreciate it.